Vite + React: Autoreload Local Library
I am working on a React + Vite project with Firebase. I share some logic between firebase functions and the frontend, so I want to extract that to a shared library. I have set my directories up up as follows:
 - src
 - functions
 - shared

I am using Vite for hot reloading pages as I make changes to them. Is there a way to configure vite so that it automatically recompiles the library in shared whenever I update it and installs the new version?

How are functions and shared updated? They are not sources, hence you don't maintain them yourself, right?

@EricMORAND Both functions and shared are in the same repository. I update the shared library with npx tsx
